# How to Link Another Website for Click in New Tab

Tags: javascript, html

I need help for Linking another Website where ever i click on my Page and that Link should open in a New Tab which should work once in every 24hours.

Comment: Are you saying no matter where someone clicks on your website, you want it to open a link to a page that is broken except for once in every 24 hours?? WHY?

Comment: what case is this??? can u elaborate more????

Comment: I need to link my other website to my current website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can help you with the first part:

```
function open_link(evt) {
    window.open("http://your.site.com");
}
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].onclick = open_link;
```

I can't help you with the once per 24 hour part. Maybe some other can?

Answer (score 1):

Add **target="_blank"** on all **a** elements.

```
<a href="link" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
```